# Find string in json column

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to check if `find_this_message` message exists inside a json column `errors` using doctrine/orm.

Here is an example of the json field:

```
[{"message_key": "another_message", "message_params": []}, {"message": "find_this_message", "message_params": []}]
```

I used the below code but it always returns nothing

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('er');

    $qb
        ->andWhere('JSON_CONTAINS(er.errors, :error) = 1')
        ->setParameter('error', '"'find_this_message'"');
    ;

 return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Doctrine ORM documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html) you should to use something like:

```
$qb->select('*')
   ->from('er', 'er')
   ->where('JSON_CONTAINS(er.errors, :error) = 1')
   ->setParameter('error', '{"message": "find_this_message"}');
```

[MySQL JSON_CONTAINS online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/5782f9daf9780db2a0fb261bf6670c67/)

Comment: I have tried it before and I got this following error:  `[PDOException (22032)]                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 1. `

Comment: Please look updated answer